# How to show snackbar on request success, failure in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, snackbar

I am using material-ui, React, Redux, and I wanna show snackbar when ever request success, failure, I am confused about where I create flag that show and hide snackbar, any help would greatly appriciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have in your store some state tracking the snackbar. e.g:

```
{
    notification: null,
}
```

a component that is rendered in the root of your app should `connect` to this part of the store.

Whenever you want to show/hide a notification, dispatch and action to change the state tracking the notifications.

Comment: yeah but it is the right way ?
because whenever we dispatch an action all the component are render.

Comment: yes, this is the correct approach, don't worry too much about re-renders as React does a great job at minimizing actual DOM changed. Remember that the component is rendered using a [virtual DOM](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom)

Comment: yeah you are right, the virtual DOM is too fast, but I don't want to rerender the hole components.

Comment: You have no choice to trigger a new render. That's the way the `Provider` works but you can ask to high level components to not launch their children rendering using the `shouldComponentUpdate` ([doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)). That's your solution.